# What's the difference between a Viewsets `create()` and `update()` and a Serializers `create()` and `update()`?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset it says "The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(), .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy()."

Over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer it says "The ModelSerializer class is the same as a regular Serializer class, except that: It includes simple default implementations of .create() and .update()."

1) Assuming there is a Viewset `UserViewSet` and router `user` and serializer `UserSerializer`. If I sent a `POST` to `/user/` does it call the `UserViewSet`'s `create()` or the `UserSerializer`'s `create()`?

2) Suppose `UserViewSet` has this permission:

```
class NoCreate(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    No one can create this object.
    """
    message = 'You do not have permission to complete the action you are trying to perform.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if view.action == "create":
            return False
        return True
```

Does the `UserSerializer`'s `create()` still get called if I send a `POST` to `/user/`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1) Assuming there is a Viewset UserViewSet and router user and serializer UserSerializer. If I sent a POST to /user/ does it call the UserViewSet's create() or the UserSerializer's create()?

Both will be called. The view's create will get the serializer, ensure the provided data are valid, call the serializer's save and will generate the response. The serializer's create will actually perform the instance creation - i.e. write it to the database.

> Does the UserSerializer's create() still get called if I send a POST to /user/?

No if the permission is set to the viewset. However, if you want to prevent any creation, you should fine tune your `ModelViewSet`:

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                  mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                  mixins.ListModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
```

Will contain all the action except the creation.

Answer (score 5):

The `.create()` and `.update()` methods in ViewSets are actions that are executed when a request is made. A request with `POST` method calls ViewSet's `.create()` method since a request with `PUT` method or `PATCH` calls the ViewSet's `.update()` method.

The `.create()` and `.update()` methods of the Serializer are executed by calling the `.save()` method of the Serializer.

Calling `.save()` will either create a new instance, or update an existing instance, depending on if an existing instance was passed when instantiating the serializer class:

```
# .save() will create a new instance.
serializer = CommentSerializer(data=data)

# .save() will update the existing `comment` instance.
serializer = CommentSerializer(comment, data=data)
```

See the [Saving Instances documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) for more details.